# How do I query an SEE encrypted database using rusqlite?

Tags: sqlite, rust, encryption, rusqlite

I have SQLite Encryption Extensions (SEE) and I'm trying to use an encrypted database in a Rust program using rusqlite. I tried getting this to work on my Linux workstation using the following test program. I also have a production service in Docker that is supposed to be encrypted as well. I can't get either to work with an encrypted database.

main.rs

```
use rusqlite::{Connection, Result};

fn main() {
    let cn = Connection::open("test.db").unwrap();
    cn.pragma_update(None, "key", "aes256:mysupersecretkey").unwrap();

    // Any query returns "file is not a database" error.
    // ...
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "sqlite_encryption"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
rusqlite = "0.30.0"
```

I do not want to use the "bundled" option for rusqlite since I need to provide my own SQLite and I am not using SQLCypher. I can get the application to build, but it won't query the database without giving an error.

I created a custom build script to simplify testing. The see-sources directory contains the sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h files that I need compiled:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Contains libsqlite3.so
export SQLITE3_LIB_DIR=pathto/sqlitelibs
export SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR=pathto/see-sources

cargo run
```

Please help me figure out how to connect to an SEE encrypted database using rusqlite.

Thank you.

Edit: Alternate possibility of answering the same question. Don't worry about SEE and just provide an example on how to statically link to a custom build of SQLite. I might be able to use the same steps to fix the problem using SEE.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77786545/5397009

Comment: That link looks like the same issue I am having. I can connect to the database manually using the sqlite3 command and issue the PRAGMA key='...' to unlock it. However, it won't work through the Rust program.